# Angle between hour and minute hand at 2:42

Tags: trigonometry

**Angle made by hour hand:**

```
       for 2 hours: 2*30 = 60

       for 42 mins: (42/60) * 30 = 21

       Total angle made by hour hand is: (60 + 21)= 81 degrees
```

**Angle made by minute hand:**

```
       for 42 min: 42*6 = 252 

       Total angle made by minute hand is: 252 degrees
```

The angle between the minute and hour hand is: (252-81) = 171 degrees

**My question is about "why is 171 degrees a wrong answer" and the correct answer is 189 degrees**

Comment: I would not expect either.  On most clocks, by 2:42 the hour hand would be considerably beyond 2; it would be closer to 3.

Comment: $171^\circ$ is the correct answer, unless a clearly defined oriented angle is meant, e.g., "counterclockwise from the hour hand to the minute hand".

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, I think orientation is defined as counterclockwise. And we should measure angles in the positive direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right image of the clock. See the angle between **hour** and **minute** hand is measured in a counterclockwise manner, hence it is more than $180^{\circ}$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for the angle between the hour and the minute, rather than the angle between the minute and the hour. See the diagram below for the discrepancy.

[image]

Comment: The figure is wrong.

Comment: The given figure is not correct, you can see the correct clock time answered by @dEmigOd